# Finding occurence in list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists containing different details which has been populated like this:

```
 [['sku','3','batchid',4], ['sku','9','batchid',5], ['sku','3','batchid',5], ['sku','3','batchid',5]]
```

I need to find the occurrence of 4 element in list of lists and to display those which appear more than once in the list of lists.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Expected output:

```
{"3":[['sku','9','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5]],
"1":[['sku','3','batchid',5]['sku','3','batchid',5]]}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye expected output

Comment: My answer does not give you the expected output, you shouldn't accept it if it's not comprehensive

Comment: @user3547740 have you seen the update in my answer?

Comment: got an error on update solution saying TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @user3547740 This is the correct list: `[['sku','3','batchid',4],['sku','9','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count 4th elements

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
print(Counter(map(itemgetter(3), lst)))
# Counter({5: 3, 4: 1}) and it will act as a normal dictionary
```

or get the most common list

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(max(lst, key=lst.count)) # ['sku', '3', 'batchid', 5]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If your expected output is

`{"3":[['sku','9','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchi‌​d',5]], 
  "1":[['sku','3','batchid',4]]}`

then here's the solution

```
from itertools import groupby
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
d = {}
for x, y in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[3]):
    y = list(y)
    d[len(y)] = y

print(d)
```

that outputs

```
{1: [['sku', '3', 'batchid', 4]],
 3: [['sku', '9', 'batchid', 5],
     ['sku', '3', 'batchid', 5],
     ['sku', '3', 'batchid', 5]]}
```

In case of multiple elements with the same number of occurrences:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[3]):
    y = list(y)
    d[len(y)].extend(y)

print(d)
```

Comment: i dint down voted but .. ihave seen many answer as soon as u answer u get an upvote. think ur doing it from other account

Comment: that guy changed my expected output..{"3":[['sku','9','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5],['sku','3','batchid',5]],
"1":[['sku','3','batchid',4]]}

Comment: there was issue in code.. say if two instance occured one 1 time . ur giving 1 as key soo. i am getting last instance accoured .other has beeen removed.